# Standardizing predictors for Neg Binom Regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, interaction, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

**tl;dr: If I include an interaction term in Negative Binomial Regression, should I standardize the predictors?**

I am analyzing a very large dataset (over 60 million observations) that has the following format:

```r
> head(df1)
   Percent_of_edges read_num Total_degree Start_degree
1:              100      327            0           12
2:              100     1854            0           12
3:              100     3567            0           12
4:              100     3846            0           12
5:              100     4094            1           12
6:              100     4102            0           12
> tail(df1)
   Percent_of_edges read_num Total_degree Start_degree
1:               40    92157            0            4
2:               40    94909            1            4
3:               40    95085            1            4
4:               40    95103            1            4
5:               40    95736            1            4
6:               40    97167            1            4
```

*Percent_of_edges*: can be either 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, or 100.

*read_num*: must be an integer between 1 and 99,999, inclusive.

*Start_degree*: must be an integer greater than 0.

*Total_degree*: must be an integer greater than 0. It must be less than or equal to *Start_degree*.

---

I've created a Negative Binomial model for this data using the following R code:

```r
(model1 <- glm.nb(End_degree ~ Percent_of_edges + read_num + 

           Percent_of_edges:read_num + offset(log(Start_degree)),

           data = df1))
```

Since I'm including an interaction term, should *Percent_of_edges* and *read_num* be standardized? (i.e., standardized using the formula: (x - μ)/sd ). In other words should I use the following R code instead?

```r
Percent_of_edges.z <- (df1$Percent_of_edges - mean(df1$Percent_of_edges))/sd(df1$Percent_of_edges)
read_num.z <- (df1$read_num - mean(df1$read_num))/sd(df1$read_num)

(model1 <- glm.nb(Total_degree ~ Percent_of_edges.z + read_num.z + 
Percent_of_edges.z:read_num.z + offset(log(Start_degree)),
       data = df1))
```

Neither *Percent_of_edges* nor *read_num* have "natural units" (e.g., kg, meter, dollar, etc.), but they describe two different things--*Percent_of_edges* is a percentage and *read_num* is a position in a chronological sequence (so a read_num of 5 means that the observation is "5th" to arrive in the sequence). I hope that makes some sense.

My goal is to create a predictive model that predicts the *Total_degree* given a *read_num*, a *Percent_of_edges*, and a *Start_degree*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When including an interaction in a regression, you should always center (= x - μ) to maintain interpretability of the main effects (by centering, main effects are calculated for the mean value of x).

Whether you divide by sd is up to you. The standardising by sd is usually done to make regression estimates directly comparable. A side effect is that it usually improves convergence of the optimiser.

p.s. - you don't have to do this by hand, in R there is the scale function for scaling predictors.